# After Using Filter, Listbox is unselectable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am planning to write a code to choose the employee from the Employees list box and add it to the assigned list. I have two list boxes left one is populated based on the project number, right one shows all the employees. When I use any of the filters, Employees list box (right one) becomes unselectable and I am not able to define the employee I want to manage. So far I used this code:

```
Private Sub FilterEmployees()
Dim strListSource As String

strListSource = "SELECT tblLU_Employee.EmployeeID, StrConv([tblLU_Employee].[FirstName],3) AS [First Name], StrConv([tblLU_Employee].[LastName],3) AS [Last Name] FROM tblLU_Employee"
If CityFilt = "" And StatusFilt = "" Then
    'no change
ElseIf CityFilt <> "" And StatusFilt <> "" Then
     strListSource = strListSource & " WHERE tblLU_Employee.Office = '" & CityFilt.Value & "'"
     strListSource = strListSource & " AND tblLU_Employee.Status = '" & StatusFilt & "'"
ElseIf CityFilt <> "" Then
     strListSource = strListSource & " WHERE tblLU_Employee.Office = '" & CityFilt.Value & "'"
ElseIf StatusFilt <> "" Then
     strListSource = strListSource & " WHERE tblLU_Employee.Status = '" & StatusFilt & "'"
End If
strListSource = strListSource & " ORDER BY tblLU_Employee.LastName"

NonAssignedList.RowSource = strListSource
Me.AllowEdits = True
NonAssignedList.AllowValueListEdits = True
```

If I don't use the filters I can select the employee I want, but If I use the filters I can't. Please check the image:
[image: Pop-up Form]

Comment: Office and Status are text type fields? Not holding a numeric ID foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Some things worth trying:

1. Add this line to your function: `NonAssignedList.Requery`
2. If that doesn't work, instead of having all that code re-write the query for the listbox, just make the query always point at the filters (with a ISNULL check in case it's empty) (see below)

Query:

```
SELECT tblLU_Employee.EmployeeID, StrConv([tblLU_Employee].[FirstName],3) AS [First Name], 
StrConv([tblLU_Employee].[LastName],3) AS [Last Name] FROM tblLU_Employee
WHERE 
    iif(ISNULL(Forms!YourFormNameHere!CityFilt), 1=1, 
        tblLU_Employee.Office = "'" & Forms!YourFormNameHere!CityFilt & "'")
    AND
    iif(ISNULL(Forms!YourFormNameHere!StatusFilt), 1=1, 
        tblLU_Employee.Status = "'" & Forms!YourFormNameHere!StatusFilt & "'")
```

Then you could trigger a requery whenever either of the filter dropdowns changes with `NonassignedList.Requery`